# How to extract the formula from a biglm object?

Tags: r, formula

How to extract the formula from a `biglm` object? I've already tried the function `as.formula()`, but it doesn't return what I expect. Example:

```
m1 = lm(Fertility ~ Agriculture + Examination + Education + Catholic + Infant.Mortality, data=swiss)
as.formula(m1) # returns only the formula expression (that's what I want!)
# returns: Fertility ~ Agriculture + Examination + Education + Catholic + Infant.Mortality

library(biglm)
m2 = biglm(Fertility ~ Agriculture + Examination + Education + Catholic + Infant.Mortality, data=swiss)
as.formula(m2) # returns many things, but I want only the formula expression
```

Comment: HINT: look at `str(m2)`

Comment: Among `biglm` attributes listed by `str(m2)`, `call` is the one which gets closer to what I want. But it still doesn't returns what I expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `terms` and `formula`:

```
formula(terms(m2))

Fertility ~ Agriculture + Examination + Education + Catholic + 
    Infant.Mortality
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you:

```
m2$call
```

Comment: `m2$call` returns: `biglm(Fertility ~ Agriculture + Examination + Education + Catholic + Infant.Mortality, data = swiss)`, but I would like it to return: `Fertility ~ Agriculture + Examination + Education + Catholic + Infant.Mortality`